# php access array by key value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a  JSON array which Im trying to parse with PHP using array_column (PHP 5.5).

My objective is to check the value of a particular key in the array and execute some additional code dependent on the result.

For example with the array below...I would like to find field_number 335 in the array and take the value (Last name) and echo to the screen. The actual array [1] could be different each time as the array grows, where as field_number would always be 335.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 286
        [lead_id] => 5
        [form_id] => 4
        [field_number] => 1
        [value] => First Name
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 287
        [lead_id] => 5
        [form_id] => 4
        [field_number] => 335
        [value] => Last name
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 288
        [lead_id] => 5
        [form_id] => 4
        [field_number] => 339
        [value] => Australia
    )
```

Hopefully that makes sense and with enough information to help someone point me in the right direction.

Many thanks all!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use array_search && array_column

```
$key = array_search('335', array_column($array, 'field_number'));
```

this should give you array id
eg. `echo $array[$key]['value'];`

Comment: glad it worked, feel free to select it as the answer :)